# How to use strike-through style in the Flowdock chat?

Tags: formatting, flowdock

Is there any possible way to use the strike-through style in the Flowdock chat, like `*` for italic, `**` for bold.

In the [help page for formatting](https://www.flowdock.com/help/chat_input#formatting), I didn't see any way to use the strike-through style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a way to use the strike-through in Flowdock from this [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#alt-h2).

Using **two tildes** is supported in Flowdock, so my issue has been solved.

> Strikethrough uses two tildes. ~~Scratch this.~~

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Strike-through]